# Jquery count <li>s in a <ul> and add custom style for the ones that aren't divideable by number 4

Tags: jquery

I'm a total jquery nube and i have a deadline, so help, usually i don't ask for easy answeres, i'm not lazy but i need help to finish the project in time.

Basically i have:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
.........
<li></li>
</ul>
```

I need a jquery function that will cound all the `<li>`'s.

Then for each

that ins't divideable by 4 (that would be

nr 1,2,3,5,6,7,9 ... etc) to add a custom style, in this case a margin right of 10 px.

Thank you,
I understand if you won't code this, just give me a hit.
Take care

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like you want a nested list...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

jQuery:

```
$('#list > li:nth-child(4n)').addClass('special');
```

CSS:

```
li { margin-right:10px; }
li.special { margin-right:0; }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nhRBG/

Comment: OP wanted everything *except* the fourth elements to have special properties. See htanata's or my answer.

Comment: @Harpyon I achieved that by setting the "special" properties on all LI elements, and then overriding those properties on all fourth LI's. The result is the same, but my solution performs faster, because jQuery is manipulating only 1/4 of all LI's whereas in your solutions 3/4 of all LI's are manipulated.

Comment: Oh, makes sense. Didn't look at the jsfiddle before I spoke.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector to do that.

```
  $('li').not(':nth-child(4n)').css('margin-right', '10px');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/agTGW/2/

Answer (score 0):

Count the li's: `$("ul#id > li").length`

Adding a custom style to elements not divisible by four isn't too complicated either. **Edit:** it's probably better to use the `:nth-child` selector, as the other answers suggest.

```
$("ul#id > li").each(function(id, element)
{
    if ((id+1) % 4 > 0)
        $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/nfq3B/

Comment: Remember that "id" or "index" as I prefer to call it, is zero-width.

Comment: @Gary, I was just about to edit that in, thanks for noticing.